# When using with SAVEPOINT and ROLLBACK , what will be the output of this?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to answer for this SQL statement.

```
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER (customerid,customername) VALUES(1,'alpha');
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER (customerid,customername) VALUES(2,'beta'); SAVEPOINT s1;
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER (customerid,customername) VALUES(3,'gamma'); SAVEPOINT s2;
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER (customerid,customername) VALUES(4,'tera'); SAVEPOINT s3;
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER (customerid,customername) VALUES(5,'omega');
ROLLBACK TO s3;

SELECT customername FROM CUSTOMER;
```

**Answers:**

1. it will give error as invalid rollback option
2. omega
3. alpha,beta,gamma,tera
4. it will give error as:there can not be multiple savepoints

Comment: Answer is option 3. alpha,beta,gamma,tera.

Comment: It is not clear which SQL dialect you're referring to. Should we guess that as well? In T-SQL for example, it would be `SAVE TRANSACTION savepoint_name` and `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION savepoint_name`. If that question is just for mysql, then please remove the sql tag.

Answer (score 1):

**SAVEPOINT name**-  Marks a savepoint within the current transaction, there can be multiple savepoints in a transaction.

**ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT name** `-ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT` rolls back the current transaction to the specified savepoint, so it discards any changes and or savepoints created after the savepoint to which you are rolling back.

So in your problem, it will rollback to the point created after the insertion of 4,tera. So the value 5, omega will be discarded. So the select query will give

```
customername
-------------
    alpha
    beta
    gamma
    tera
```

Answer (score 1):

In mysql we get the following error:
 SAVEPOINT s3 does not exist
but the select statement will work and gives the following result:

### customername

```
alpha
beta
gamma
tera
```